# date in a cell to change when any cell in that row is modified

Tags: excel

I'm relatively new to excel and need some advice.  I'm using excel 2016. I have read through other posts and can't find anything that really matches. Does anyone know how to get a cell in a row to change to todays date only when any other cell in that row is changed? And secondly if that  date in that cell is more than week old and the value of another cell in the same row is "open" then change the fill color? thanks for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some VBA for this. Get into Visual Basic Editor (VBE) with Alt+F11. In your VBAProject (your workbook in the Project window) double click the sheet that contains the cell in which you are wanting to detect a change. Then add the following::

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Detect if cell A1 has had a change
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then

        'Change cell B2 to todays date
        Range("B2").Value = Now()

    'Detect if value in cell C2 is changed to "Open"
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2")) Is Nothing Then

        'Is the date in B2 older than a week from now?
        If DateAdd("d", -7, Now()) > Range("B2").Value Then

            'Change the cell color of B2
            Range("B2").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 255) 'Cyan... it's so beautiful
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

That subroutine is a special subroutine that runs when any cell changes value in the worksheet in which the subroutine is placed. We detect if a change was made to a specific cell with that awful `If Not Intersect(...` line. Then it's pretty straight VBA to change values and colors of cells and do some date arithmetic and tests and whatnot.

Comment: Thanks JNevill. since I need it to look at more than one cell in the row do I just change A1 to a range like A1:j1? and I need the color to be red?

Comment: It depends on your needs. If you are wanting to detect if a change happened in more than once cell than `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:J1")) Is Nothing` is perfectly valid. You've got a problem with cyan? Red is `RGB(255,0,0)` you can check out a site like [colorpicker.com](http://www.colorpicker.com/) (The R,G, B values specifically) to help with the color codes.

Comment: Thanks again for your support JNevill. Soon as I get home I'm going to try this

Comment: I've entered it like this and it is saying invalid procedure name:

Comment: "If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:J1")) Is Nothing" is red in the editor

Comment: Did you include all of that code. Including the `PRIVATE Sub Worksheet...` and `End Sub` line? If it's still balking, then you can use the drop downs at the top of the code editting window to select "Worksheet" and "Change" and it will create the subroutine, in which you can just paste the rest of the code. [Check out this website](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html) for a quick primer on VBA events and how to use them.

Comment: I added every line you posted the first time except for changing the one line to include the target range of A1:J1